# Monitor JMS queue with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jms

Is it possible to view JMS data (such as counters and content) as well as executing management commands (such as flushing the queue) from Idea IDE?

Gil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at [SoapUi plugin](http://www.soapui.org/IDE-Plugins/intellij.html)

It provide [JMS support](http://www.soapui.org/JMS/getting-started.html)